# TypeError at /login Strings must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, django, encoding, hash

I am facing an error from this Django project. I have tried all the advice i can come across still its not working properly.
Below is the error from the web.

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.9.7

    Installed Applications:
    ['main',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django_filters']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner

    34. response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.`response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)` 

File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\main\views.py" in login
  171.`hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST['login_password'], bcrypt.gensalt())`

File "C:\Users\INTROVERTED\Downloads\Compressed\FacialRecognitionForPolice-master\venv1\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py" in hashpw
  79.`raise TypeError("Strings must be encoded before hashing")`

Exception Type: TypeError at /login
Exception Value: Strings must be encoded before hashing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message clearly says, you have to encode the password first.

In `main/views.py` on line 171 you have

```py
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST['login_password'], bcrypt.gensalt())
```

Your `request.POST` data is a string, so you should encode it to bytes:

```py
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST['login_password'].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())
```

You can select other encoding (not default `utf8`) with `.encode('ascii')` (choose one and don't change it later, `utf8` is probably the best choice in general).

Comment: thanks a lot @SUTeliakov........ i feel so stupid ryt now... really appreciated