# bcrypt error : TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt

This is a little part of the code:

```
elif b== "hashing" :
    d=input("what  do you want to hash ")

    bl=bcrypt.hashpw(d,bcrypt.gensalt)
    print(bl)
```

I was trying to hash something the user entered and hash it and print it for the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError at /login Strings must be encoded before hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72455155/typeerror-at-login-strings-must-be-encoded-before-hashing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message says, you have to encode the string into bytes before you can hash it.  e.g.

```
bl = bcrypt.hashpw(d.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt)
```

A string in Python is a relatively abstract thing, but hashing operates on a concrete series of bytes. A string can be encoded into bytes, but there's more than one way to do it, so Python doesn't do it for you automatically (except when you write to an output channel with a defined encoding).

The usual encoding is UTF-8, but you could also do UTF-16 or UTF-32 (both of which give you the additional option of using big-endian or little-endian order). You could even encode into some non-Unicode format like Latin-1 or plain ASCII, as long as all the characters in the string are representable in the target character set.

Answer (score 0):

**you have to encode the string first :**

```
import bcrypt
d = "hello"
bl = bcrypt.hashpw(d.encode(), salt=bcrypt.gensalt())
print(bl)
```

Comment: Please explain how this answer is different from a previous one posted 30 minutes ago.

Comment: When i wrote the post i answered an other question before so i have to wait 30 min, so i didn't see that there is an answer.